# I'm getting an operational error, as described below, when trying to connect to a remote postgreSQL server through sqlalchemy

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

Here is the error message:

```
OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: No route to host
    Is the server running on host "5432" (0.0.21.56) and accepting
    TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

Here's what I've tried:

```
import sqlalchemy 
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.ext.automap import automap_base
from sqlalchemy.orm import Session
engine = create_engine('postgresql+psycopg2://tcccinxdlfzchw:86b3a71b125f827c343a88d71811fa2096744455e75abd5b5e15077bb7a910cb@5432/d2lr09vchdiec3')

Base = automap_base()

Base.prepare(engine, reflect=True)
```

It's from this base.prepare that I am getting the above error message, and I have tried modifying my postgresql.conf file to listen to all addresses, and my pg-hba.conf file to be
host all all md5. Then restarted the server, and I'm still getting the error. Have any idea?

Comment: Looks like you missed `host` part somewhere. Your code sees PgSQL port number `5432` as a host and interprets it as IP address `0.0.21.56`.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what it means that I missed host part? Is there some code I should fix?

Comment: So, it looks like you got it

Comment: Yep thank for your help! Thankfully it was easier than it seemed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, the engine wasn't connecting simply because I wasn't providing the correct URI, which can usually be found in the details of your host site, next to port number, password, etc.